# Density function of random variable conditioned on sum of independent Gaussians

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

First time posting on the Math StackExchange, so apologies if I violate any rules.

I'm trying to understand how the solution given to [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2249667) can be generalized to the case where the sum of two independent Gaussians, $X$ and $Y$, must be larger than *any value*, not just 0.

Here's the original problem:

"I have two Gaussian independent random variables $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_x^2,), Y \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_y^2,)$. I have to find the density of $X$ given that $X + Y > 0$.

I know that $X, X+Y$ shall be jointly normal distributed and I also know the forms of conditional distribution of $X | X+Y=z$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/signal-extraction-problem-conditional-expectation-of-one-item-in-sum-of-indepen

but somehow I am confused because the condition that I have is that $X+Y > 0$ and not of the form $X+Y = z$.

I feel that some integration shall have to be performed but I am not sure how. Any pointers shall be very helpful. It will also help if I can get the conditional mean, variance if not the entire density function."

**I'm trying to generalize this problem to the case where $X$ + $Y$ > $z$, where z is any value.**

Particular constraints:

1. $\sigma^{2}_x = 1 - \sigma^{2}_y$
2. $0 < \sigma^{2}_x, \sigma^{2}_y < 1$

I've attempted to develop an intuition for this by running some simulations. Interestingly, it seems that:

- The skewness of the resulting distribution scales exponentially with $\sigma^{2}_x$.
- The variance of the distribution has a cubic relationship with $\sigma^{2}_x$ (i.e., an upside-down J shape)
- And the mean of the distribution is essentially a linear function of $\sigma^{2}_x$ (perhaps slightly concave up).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It would be convenient (and would increase the probability of receiving an answer) if you gave the precise formulation of the question you are interested in.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've updated the question.

Comment: If $z=0$, then the pdf for $X|X+Y>0$ is $\frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2 \sigma_x^2}} \left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2-2 \sigma_x ^2}}\right)+1\right)}{\sqrt{2 \pi } \sigma_x}$ when $0<\sigma_x^2<1$.  I don't think there's a nice closed-form for the pdf for other values of $z$ or for the cdf.

Comment: I was wrong.  There is a closed-form when $z\neq 0$.  I'll add that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Given that $X\sim N(0,\sigma^2_x)$ and $Y\sim N(0,1-\sigma^2_x)$ which are independent with the restriction $0<\sigma^2_x<1$ one wants to know the probability density function of $X|X+Y>z$.  That pdf is

$$\frac{f_X(x) \int_{z-x}^{\infty }  f_Y(y) \, dy}{\Pr (X+Y>z)}=\frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2 \sigma_x^2}} \Phi \left(\frac{x-z}{\sqrt{1-\sigma_x^2}}\right)}{\sqrt{2 \pi } \sigma_x \Phi (-z)}$$